# Error:This project does not use the Gradle build system, even though it was build in gradle system before

Tags: android-studio, gradle

My project was build initally with bradle build system in android studio after I switching branches in git I got the following error.

**This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.**

When i try exetuting gradle task I get error :
**Error:Android Source Generator: [project-name] AndroidManifest.xml file not found**  , Even though I have the file in proper place.

I have been trying to fix this from several days. I have tried re-importing the project,  clone the project again. Any help is gladly welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: can you provide your project folder structure?